# Проблемы с обновлением пакетов в Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

[image: фото терминала с ошибкой]

Я решил обновить все пакеты в kali, с помощью команды, которую я написал в самом низу картинки. Все пакеты загрузились и стали распаковываться. Но потом произошла ошибка, котрую вы можете видеть на картинке. В итоге установка прервалась.

Как исправить эту ошибку? И как мне возобновить установку пакетов?

Ошибка:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
  files list for package 'libtwolame:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an erroe code (2)
```

Команда для запуска обновлений:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y full-upgrade
```

Comment: Возможно, поможет это https://askubuntu.com/a/947374/932746

Comment: Возможно и поможет. А как возобновить установку?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Ок, я добавил текстовый вариант. Теперь поможешь?